# Robot Framework Selenium Go To Keyword blocked by browser popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, autoit

I am trying to use the Go To Keyword to navigate to a page. 
When you navigate to this page there is a browser popup that you need to use to log in.

The problem I am encountering is that this popup blocks Robot Framework from recognizing that the Go To Keyword has been completed. I have steps in my testcase to try to log in using this popup, but they never get executed because it just gets stuck on the Go To Keyword.

One workaround I tried is to put the Go To Keyword in a separate user created keyword with a timeout of 2 seconds, and then run that keyword in the testcase prefaced with the Run Keyword and continue on failure Keyword. But for some reason the popup blocks even this timeout from triggering and it's still stuck until I manually close the popup.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this turned out to be was an issue with single-sign-on.
I had logged into the website environment with a fun account, when opening this page information was being retrieved from a different domain.
Usually when you are logged in with your company account this information is used to acces the second domain.
But because my fun account does not exist in that domain this failed and the popup appeared. Because the popup is a Windows element and not a Chrome element Selenium could not handle it.

We talked about a possible solution and the best method seems to be to use the AutoItLibrary and use the RunAs Keyword to start Chrome as a user with the credentials for the second domain.
I did not fully flesh out this method because is has incompatibility issues with the way we want to execute our automatic test suite. But I wanted to put it here for reference for anyone else encountering this problem.